# Android simpledateformat time check

Tags: android, simpledateformat

Im trying to make a check-in check-out feature where a user can not check-in until the time specified. in this example, Ill say they can not check in until 10:00PM

schedule_start string = 10:00 its in a 24 hour format

if the user attempts to check-in before 10:00 an alertdialog box will appear telling them its to early and try checking back at 10:00

My problem is the alertdialog box always appear, even after the time specified.

Can someone help steer me in the right direction please?

```
    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("k:m");   

    try {
        Date d = parserSDF.parse(schedule_start);   
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();      
        Date CurrentTime = now.getTime(); 

        if (d.before(CurrentTime))  { 

            tooearlytocheckin = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    screen1.this).create(); 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = tooearlytocheckin.getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.dimAmount = .30f; 
            tooearlytocheckin.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            tooearlytocheckin.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            tooearlytocheckin.setTitle("              WARNING");
            tooearlytocheckin.setCancelable(false);
            tooearlytocheckin.setMessage("It is still too early for you to check in." + " Try back at " + (schedule_start));

            tooearlytocheckin.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    DefaultWidgetVisibilityGONE();
                    CancelInButtonInstructions();  // <--- Use this setting for displaying view after pressing Okay


                    vib.vibrate(40);
                }
            });
            tooearlytocheckin.show();

            if (d.after(CurrentTime))   {
            CheckInToggleButtonInstructions();
            }
        }

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {                                         
        e1.printStackTrace();                   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pointers:

```
SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("k:m");
```

By using `k` you are asking for 1-24 hour time, not 0-23... I believe you want `HH:mm`.

```
Date d = parserSDF.parse("10:00");
```

This sets the hours and minutes to 10AM but the date is unspecified so it defaults to: 1-1-1970... `d` was always before `CurrentTime` because 1970 < 2012. You could simply call `new Date()` to retrieve the current date & time then set the appropriate time of day, but all the Date.set() method are deprecated in favor of Calendar objects. So let's switch to the Calendar class:

```
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar scheduled = Calendar.getInstance();
scheduled.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
scheduled.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
scheduled.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

if(scheduled.before(current)) {
    // Do as you please
}
```

With this method we do not bring in the overhead associated with try-catch blocks or any class other than Calendar. Hope that helps.

**Addition from comments**

If users are presented different user times and you currently retrieve the time in the format "hour:minute" then use this:

```
// scheduled_start looks like "23:45"
String[] times = scheduled_start.split(":");
int hour = Integer.parseInt(times[0]); // this'll be 23
int minute = Integer.parseInt(times[1]); // this'll be 45
```

with:

```
scheduled.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
scheduled.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

Comment: I think you may be on to something, however the String schedule_start will not always be set to 10:00, each user has their own unique time on when to check in like user A can check in at 10:00 and user B can check in at 5:00 etc... so im not sure if what you suggested could help. But thanks for your reply! would you happen to have a few new pointers for me?

Comment: Allowing for individual check-in times is easy enough. Where is the check-in time for each user stored?

Comment: its stored in a SQL database that the user will hit based on their user info credentials and the database spits out a json format of their information

Comment: I updated my answer to parse the String format that you already have.

Comment: I really do appreciate all of your efforts on helping me Sam, Your suggestion worked! The only thing I changed was if(scheduled.before(current)) i changed it to if(current.before(scheduled)) THANKS!!!!